# How to set an environment variable for a specific game on Steam for Linux?

Tags: steam

Well, how? There is that "SET LAUNCH OPTIONS" button, but I believe that is only fit to command line switches.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is possible to prefix the command with your environment variable in the [set launch options](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947) like so:

```
YOUR_VARIABLE=1 %command%
```

Comment: Does this still work? The linked docs don't mention it.

Comment: It really works according to `/proc/<game pid>/environ`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple options?

Would separating them with semicolons work?

Comment: You just leave a space, so my current one is `mesa_glthread=true R600_DEBUG=sbcl,hyperz,llvm,sisched,forcedma vblank_mode=0 %command%`.

Comment: Jan 2023 - it does indeed still seem to work

Comment: Does this not work anymore? Starting the game errors out saying it cannot find `OPENSSL_ia32cap=~0x200000200000000`

my Launch Option: `OPENSSL_ia32cap=~0x200000200000000 %command%`