# Set custom appdata environment variable for a Steam app

Tags: windows, environment-variables, steam

I have user name with non-latin characters and this really messes up some of my Steam apps.
I need a way to launch these apps with a custom `APPDATA`.

I tried to use bat file to launch Steam:

```
set APPDATA=C:\Users\LatinName\AppData\Roaming
start "" "path\to\steam.exe"
```

And tried to do the same in powershell:

```
$env:APPDATA='C:\Users\LatinName\AppData\Roaming'
& 'path\to\steam.exe'
```

Also tried to create a bat file and to set it as a custom launch command in Steam (so Steam would launch this file and it will launch a game):

```
set APPDATA=C:\Users\LatinName\AppData\Roaming
start "" "path/to/game.exe"
```

But it didn't work, app still uses default appdata path. I thought that child processes should inherit variables.

I tried [an answer from this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/954041/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-for-an-specific-game-on-steam-for-linux) but Steam just says that it can't find `APPDATA=C:\Users\Avorion\AppData\Roaming`.

The other 2 ways are renaming my current profile or creating a new one.

- Renaming profile on Windows 10 is a long and not safe process.
- Creating a new profile requires me to set every setting again and for some reason makes my PC much slower, so it's not an option.

Comment: What errors did you see when launching those games with non-latin path?

Comment: Game stores settings and images in the AppData and for some reason has troubles with getting some of them. The devs know about this, I just want a workaround for now tbh.

Comment: I already wrote why creating another user is not a good idea.

Comment: As a workaround you can try to create a directory symbolic link with `mklink /D` command.

Comment: But appdata will still have non-latin username. Isn't symbolic link just alternate name? If I'm incorrect, please explain.